# How to sleep a C++ Boost Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, sleep

Seems impossible to sleep a thread using boost::thread.
Method sleep requires a system_time but how can I build it?

Looking inside libraries doesn't really help much...

Basically I have a thread
inside the function that I pass to this thread as entry point, I would like to call something like

```
 boost::this_thread::sleep
```

or something, how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Depending on your version of Boost:

Either...

```
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 

boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

Or...

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 

boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
```

You can also use microseconds, seconds, minutes, hours and maybe some others, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, thank you... I didn't pay attention using this_thread but just boost::thread and nothing worked:) Thansk

Comment: This gives me the following error (using Xcode 5 / LLVM): error: no viable conversion from 'boost::posix_time::microseconds' (aka 'subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000>') to 'const system_time' (aka 'const boost::posix_time::ptime')

Comment: use `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` instead of  `boost::this_thread::sleep`, the latter is deprecated, see [boost::this_thread::sleep](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.sleep).

Answer (score 23):

From another post, I learned `boost::this_thread::sleep` is deprecated for Boost v1.5.3: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html

Instead, try

```
void sleep_for(const chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time);
```

e.g.

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(60));
```

Or maybe try

```
void sleep_until(const chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& abs_time);
```

I was using Boost v1.53 with the deprecated `sleep` function, and it aperiodically crashed the program.  When I changed calls to the `sleep` function to calls to the `sleep_for` function, the program stopped crashing.

Answer (score 4):

firstly

```
boost::posix_time::seconds secTime(1);  
boost::this_thread::sleep(secTime);
```

secondly

```
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

I learned the hard way that at least in MS Visual Studio (tried 2013 and 2015) there is the huge difference between

```
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(SmallIterval));
```

and

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::microseconds(SmallIterval));
or
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(SmallIterval));
```

when interval is smaller than some rather substantial threshold (I saw threshold of 15000 microseconds = 15 milliseconds).

If SmallIterval is small, sleep() does instantaneous interruption. sleep(100 mks) behaves as sleep(0 mks).

But sleep_for() for the time interval smaller than a threshold pauses for the entire threshold. sleep_for(100 mks) behaves as sleep_for(15000 mks).

Behavior for intervals larger than threshold and for value 0 is the same.